# Prevent moving of window in Xorg

Tags: x11, window-manager, window

I'm running a single windowed application (chromium) via `startx`.
How can I prevent the application from moving its' window?

(As there is no maximize functionality without window manager, it's hard to get a moved window back in place.)

Comment: Who's moving the window? Without a window manager, there's no way to move a window unless the application itself does it.

Answer (score 1):

Without a window manager, there's no way for the user to move a window. The application would have to do it itself (or a program that the user invokes through the command line or some equally unlikely way).

With a window manager, providing ways to move windows or to prevent windows from moving is the window manager's responsibility.

I don't think Chromium tries to move its own windows, so you don't need to take any special steps to prevent it from being moved. Just start it at position +0+0 with the same size as the screen.

Start Chromium with the `--kiosk` option to make it run full-screen. See also [How to open Chromium in full screen kiosk mode in minimal windows manager environment (like openbox / jwm)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487488/how-to-open-chromium-in-full-screen-kiosk-mode-in-minimal-windows-manager-enviro) and [setting up a kiosk with chromium](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/setting-up-a-kiosk-with-chromium).

Comment: Chromium indeed tries to move it.
If you drag on an existing tab it will move the window. But i get your point regarding the moving of windows without title bar.